# NPAPI plugin refresh issue in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, npapi, firebreath

Or ... "When to call pluginWindowMac::InvalidateWindow()"?

Apologies. It's hard to be brief here, it's a fairly specific test case.

I'm testing an NPAPI plugin (now adapted to Firebreath) under Firefox,Safari,Chrome and IE.
I'm testing the plugin under both Windows and OS X.

It's a video player using OpenGL for all rendering. So on OS X I'm using a CAOpenGLLayer
derived class, and supporting the Invalidating Core Animation model, which is used under
both Firefox and Chrome.

The plugin is running well in all cases and on both platforms, except for Chrome (v26.0.1410.65) on OS X, where I'm seeing a weird 'refresh' issue under both OS X 10.6
and 10.7.

It's as if Chrome is double-buffering the composited layer somewhere. It's always one
'frame' behind the one drawn via OpenGL. I've proved this by numbering each draw call
and drawing that number into the OpenGL render as well as logging it via NSLog. What's
on screen is always one behind the logged draw callback (I'm not rendering video at
this point - it's paused).

By using a specific keyboard event to trigger a extra call to pluginWindowMac::InvalidateWindow(),
I can force an external invalidate that will bring what's on screen into sync with
what was last rendered, but it will lose sync again on the next draw call (triggered
by the layer setNeedsDisplay).

I'm presently calling pluginWindowMac::InvalidateWindow() at the end of each draw
callback. In other words at the end of the layer 'drawInCGLContext()' call. This would
seem to be the only logical place to do it.  But I'm beginning to suspect that under
Chrome this just isn't working? Clearly the call works - as proved by the keyboard
triggered InvalidateWindow, but maybe it doesn't work from inside drawInCGLContext?

The plugin is running fine under Firefox (the other browser that uses Invalidating
Core Animation). But maybe that simply doesn't rely on a working pluginWindowMac::InvalidateWindow()?

Has anyone else tripped over this issue with Chrome?  Any workarounds discovered? About
all I can think of right now is some kind of timer driven event to trigger an extra
Invalidate.

Comment: One thing you might try is to change to using async OpenGLCALayer and then use the autoinvalidate to trigger the draw

Comment: Please file a bug at crbug.com (ideally with minimal plugin code to reproduce it).

Comment: Thanks Richard, that would solve (or at least hide) the problem, but I'm kind of worried about the extra CPU load. I'm being miserly there as we plan to support multiple audio channels and lots of other goodies on fairly low-level platforms (hence the 10.6 testing).

Comment: smorgan. Thanks. I do plan to try and isolate the issue in a simple plugin test case.  It may well expose a problem in my code. But as with all things, it depends on time available. At the moment the only effect of this glitch is to prevent the 'static' status display of the player (when NOT playing video) from being updated.